Is the average force diagram correctly put together?
I have done a cut in an object to perform calculations of where the object experiences the most stress (the most critical point). The cut will create Shear force (V) although this will be 0, axial force (P) and bending moment (M). F_L is a force from a load, which is why the object (before cut) will experience a lot of stress. I was wondering if the average force diagrams in the green square is correctly put together, the left diagram shows the bending moment in vertical beam, and the diagram to the right shows the axial stress pressing down on the horizontal beam. If i add these diagrams together, I will find the total stress on the object, but will it look like the diagram on the bottom? The object before cut will look like an "L". 

Is that green box supposed to represent the loads on the horizontal beam? If so where does the uniform load come from?

$x'=x_1+x_2$ in the box is very confusing, you should not be adding lengths but stresses in the cut. That being said, the distributions in the box look plausible.
